# Returning values from child-classes

Tags: java

I want to be able to call the `ObjectAction#firstClick` in a dynamic way which has support for more classes. My goal is not to access the Test class directly and call it from there.

Keep in mind you may not use static contexts.

```
public abstract class ObjectAction implements AchievementListener {

    public abstract void firstClick(GameObject object);

}
```

`firstClick` is what I want to call in a dynamic way..

Here is more code..

```
public interface AchievementListener {    
}
```

This acts as the listener type which has child-classes such as `ObjectAction`, `ItemAction`, `GroundAction` etc.

Here is the enum

```
public enum Achievements {
    TEST(new ObjectAction() {
        @Override
        public void firstClick(Object object) {

      }

    }); 

    private static final Set<Achievements> ACHIEVEMENTS = Collections.unmodifiableSet(
            EnumSet.allOf(Achievements.class));

    public static Optional<AchievementListener> getListener() {
        return ACHIEVEMENTS.stream().filter(a -> a.listener).findAny();
    }

    AchievementListener listener;

    Achievements(AchievementListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }
}
```

The #getListener() function is the part I need help with, it doesn't work atm because it isnt'returning an AchievementListener, what i'm looking for is something like getListener().getObjectActions().firstClick(GameObject object); and for something like ItemActions it should be getListener().getItemActions().executeAction(Item item);

Answer (score 1):

You have created an interface which doesn't declare any methods. Then you implement that interface at an abstract class which only declares that one abstract method; thus you don't need that abstract class because you are not doing anything with a necessary constructor. [Read more on abstract classes and interfaces here](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077421/learn-java/abstract-classes-vs-interfaces.html).

What you need to do is to declare the interface like this:

```
public interface AchievementListener {
    public void firstClick(GameObject object); // Declared the interface method
}
```

You can leave the abstract class now because it has no use and directly ask for a `AchievementListener`:

```
public class Test extends Achievement {
     @Override
     public AchievementListener process (Player player) {
         return new AchievementListener () {
             @Override
             public void firstClick(GameObject object) {
                 System.out.println("This works for sure ;)");
             }
         };
     }
}
```

So in short, the dynamic is in the interface, because you want that one method in all of your child classes!

Comment: That's not what I asked dude.. Now what if I had an GroundAction class with a method named firstClick(GroundObject object) ???? 

And how would we execute that firstClick.. How would we call it.. AchievementListener.firstClick(object); will not work because it's not static.....

Comment: @QuestionsDaily I dont like that attitude, I am only trying to help you in my own free time. I will try one more time, but I think you need to show in what use-case you need it because I can ramble into generics without helping you. Be more clear with your explanation and actually show the use-case.

Comment: sorry man, didn't mean it like that but people keep answering things i never asked for, then again I apologize... I need a way to call firstClick(GameObject);

I've added an example @ main-post.